# jQuery and jQuery plugin unique id select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

I'm using https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ plugin.  I need to be able to select unique element id's that were dynamically loaded from the database.

```
 <div><a id="1" href="1">1</a></div>
 <div><a id="2" href="2">2</a></div>
 <div><a id="3" href="2">3</a></div>
```

Jquery

```
 $('#1').confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
    confirm: function(){
      console.log(this.content);
    },
    cancel: function(){
      $.alert('Canceled!')
    }
 });
```

My question is how could I select an element's id when clicked. I know how to do it with plain JavaScript. A little more info about what I'm trying to do. It's blog entries generated dynamically from the database. Each div represents a blog post and the `<a>` tag represents the icon that when pressed is going to call ajax to delete that blog post. After you confirm that you really want to delete.

In JavaScript I would do something like this.

```
 <div><a  id="1"  href="1" onclick="many(this.id)">1</a></div>
 <div><a  id="2" href="2" onclick="many(this.id)">2</a></div>
 <div><a  id="3" href="2" onclick="many(this.id)">3</a></div>
```

the script

```
   function many(id) 
{
///ajax call 

}
```

I just don't want JavaScript's default confirm box, so I'm going with a jQuery plug-in.

Also tried doing something like this, but jQuery doesn't work from inside a JavaScript function

```
     function many(id) 
{
    $('#'+id).confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
    confirm: function(){
      console.log(this.content);
    },
    cancel: function(){
      $.alert('Canceled!')
    }
 });
}
```

PHP while loop

```
<?php  while ($row = $result->fetch()){ ?>
<article id="<?php echo $row['article_id'];?>">
    <div class="body>
       <h1><?php echo $row['title'];?></h1>
       <p><?php echo $row['article'];?></p>
       <div><a id="<?php echo $row['article_id'];?>" class="delete">x</a></div>
    </div>
</article>
<?php }?>
```

This is what ended up working for me.

```
$('.someClass').click( function(event) {
    var ele = $(this).attr('rel');
    // ele is the element you clicked on
    $.confirm({
    title: 'Delete!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
    confirm: function(){
         var dataString = "blogpost="+ele;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/new12/scripts/delete_blog_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                if(html)
                {

                    $("#aid"+ele).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });

                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    },
    cancel: function(){
      $.alert('Canceled!')
    }
 });

});
```

After a confirm press I do a Ajax call. On success, it deletes fades out the element and with a call back function to remove the element from the DOM.
Thanks for everyone that tried to help.

Comment: how are the div's generated? Are they hardcoded as html or generated by php (what you didn't show)?

Comment: They come from a while loop results from a database.

Comment: Can you show the php-code for that? Was Dan Def's answer already a solution that did work for you?

Comment: ok I will edit to show the php code

Comment: but if your problem is solved with Dan Def's answer (which is good) you don't need that anymore.

Comment: Ill try Dan's code

Comment: You could of course also search for the class delete: `$('.delete').confirm({...`

Comment: or modifying @Dan Def's answer with the new code shown: `$('.body').find('a').on('click', confirm)`

Comment: Based on comments in the other question I have added the confirm event handler to my answer for clarity. Does that achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: I have just looked at the plugin and the confirm function is directly on the $ object. I have have updated my answer to show this. Does this work?

Comment: I'm going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to call `.confirm()` on the clicked element? Try this, you don't need to know the ID because inside of callback functions in jquery event handlers, `this` refers to the element that the event was triggered on.

```
$('a').click(function () {
  $(this).confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
    confirm: function(){
      console.log(this.content);
    },
    cancel: function(){
      $.alert('Canceled!')
    }
 })
});
```

I would add, however, that Dan Def is correct about the fact that you'll probably want to wrap these elements in a surrounding `div` so that you don't add a click handler to *every* `a` tag on the page. So in that case, instead of `$('a').click(...)` in the snippet above, it would be `$('#divId').find('a').click(...)`

Comment: Dan Def's answer simply has a function called `confirm` passed as the callback to the event handler. This won't magically work on its own and assumes that a function called `confirm` has been defined that takes an event as a parameter and calls the jquery plugin function on the event target. That fact is not necessarily clear to a beginner, especially since `confirm` matches the name of the jquery plugin function being used by the OP, making it doubly confusing. My answer expands on Dan Def's by providing a full working example and some additional explanation.

Comment: No go, I'm open to any other suggestions on how to go about implementing a confirm box specially if is in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Which part of it isn't working? Is there a console error? If you don't need to use the jquery confirm plugin, just replace everything inside of the click function with `if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete!')){ //insert delete logic here }` There's no reason why you can't use a standard javascript `confirm` from within a jquery event handler. If you need to get the ID of the clicked element from within the `if` statement, just use `this.id`

Comment: no errors on console logo. The plugin doesn't work. NO alert box. Yeah I have done the pure JavaScript way before. Its just not that pretty. Was looking around for other options.

Comment: If anything ill just do it with pure JavaScript. Leave it for later.

Comment: I have solved it. I did something similar to what you did. Works very well thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could place your generated div elements inside another container and then do something like:

```
$('#MyContainer').find('a').on('click', confirm)
```

Edit: For clarity the confirm function would look like the following:

```
 function confirm(event) {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
        confirm: function(){
            console.log(this.content);
        },
        cancel: function(){
             $.alert('Canceled!')
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @jeff yeah you're right I didn't see that he'd already done that. Have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

U need multiple selector... an example could be...:

```
$('#1, #2, #3').on('click', confirm);
```

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
var confirm = $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: 'Are you sure you want to delete!',
    confirm: function(){
          console.log(this.content);

    },
    cancel: function(){
        $.alert('Canceled!')
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok so the html is basically just an example, It's blog post from a database with unique blog post id's so it could be many results per page.